# Cloudinary jQuery Add HTML Element to Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary for my image management.  I am calling the image using:

```
$.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id, {
    format: "jpg", width: 300, height: 200, crop: "fill"
})
```

Does anyone know how I can add an html element to this image such as `style="max-width: 100%"`? I can't seem to find it in their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this might be a little different from your approach, but functionally it could do the same thing by adding a custom class on your image element and then change the style from there.

In your example:

***js:***

```
$.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id, {
    format: "jpg", width: 300, height: 200, crop: "fill", class: "your-custom-class"
});
```

***css***

```
.your-custom-class {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

The Documentation is here: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_image_manipulation
Check the **Lazy loading and dynamic transformations** section.

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly set the `style` attribute, for example:

```
$.cloudinary.image(data.result.public_id, {format: "jpg", width: 300, height: 200, crop: "fill", style: "max-width:100%" })
```